# Get the key of an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm currently fetching an array with .each:

```
$.each(messages, function(key,message){ doStuff(); });
```

But the key is the index of the array and not the associative key.

How can I get it easily?

Comment: An array doesn't have any associative key. The index is the key. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Where is you Array i.e `messages`? post that

Comment: Could you please provide an example array (2-3 elements) and what "associative key" you expect?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. In JS you can use object to simulate that using square bracket notation, but you're adding properties. I believe you made the common mistake to have something like: `var h = new Array(); h['foo'] = 'bar'`. But you didn't added a new array's element, you just added a new property called 'foo'. In fact, `alert(h.length)` will be `0`, and you will have `alert(h.foo)` equals to 'bar'.

Comment: "key is the index of the array and not the associative key".  What do you mean?  Array's don't have "associative keys".  Can you show us what `messages` is, and what values you're looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var data = {
    val1 : 'text1',
    val2 : 'text2',
    val3 : 'text3'
};
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    alert( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'" );
});
​
```

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qTv9/)

Answer (score 21):

JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays". It has arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And objects:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
```

Array's don't have "keys". They have indices, which are counted starting at 0.

Arrays are accessed using `[]`, and objects can be accessed using `[]` or `.`.

Example:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
array[1] = 4;
console.log(array); // [1,4,3]

var obj = {};
obj.test = 16;
obj['123'] = 24;
console.log(obj); // {test: 16, 123: 24}
```

If you try to access an array using a string as a key instead of an int, that may cause problems. You would be setting a property of the array and not a value.

```
var array = [1,2,3];
array['test'] = 4; // This doesn't set a value in the array
console.log(array); // [1,2,3]
console.log(array.test); // 4
```

jQuery's `$.each` works with both of these. In the callback for `$.each`, the first parameter, `key`, is either the object's key, or the array's index.

```
$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(key, value){
    console.log(key); // Logs 0 1 2 3 4
});

$.each({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}, function(key, value){
    console.log(key); // Logs 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
});
```

Comment: Kudos for the neat JQuery each method!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays" as in PHP, but objects. Objects, though, may have string keys that corresponds to a value. Arrays are lists of values indexed *numerically*, so, if `key` is a number, it must be an array you are working with and not an object, and therefore you cannot get the key, as there is none.

Thus, you'd probably want to iterate over an array with a simple `for`-loop instead of a callback-based iterator such as `$.each`.